# how to disable button jquery or html

Tags: jquery, html, button

I need to disable a button if there are no records returned in a db query.
What i have is this:

```
  $cnt= mysql_num_rows($qry_resultcnt);
  if ($ttrec >=1)
  {
  echo "msgbox";
  document.getElementById("btn1").disabled = true;//disable insert button??
  }
```

but this returns a error message

```
   Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '='
```

Comment: @DhavalMarthak are you sure? It doesn't seem odd to try and execute JavaScript in the midst of PHP tags?

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: This looks like a mixture of PHP and javascript.  PHP can't execute Javascript and vice versa.  If you enclose the javascript in script tags and echo it as a string It will probably get you what you want.  But this should be handled by the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing php with javascript, which is not allowed. Try either of the two options below to escape your javascript from php.

```
$cnt= mysql_num_rows($qry_resultcnt);
if ($ttrec >=1) {
  echo "msgbox";
  echo '<script>document.getElementById("btn1").disabled = true;</script>';
}
```

Or....

```
$cnt= mysql_num_rows($qry_resultcnt);
if ($ttrec >=1) {
  echo "msgbox";
  ?>
  <script>
    document.getElementById("btn1").disabled = true;
  </script>
  <?php
}
```

Although for both options, I would recommend wrapping your JS in a self invoking function so that you are certainly firing it, like so...

```
echo '<script> (function() { document.getElementById("btn1").disabled = true; })(); </script>';
```

OR....

```
<script>
  (function() { 
    document.getElementById("btn1").disabled = true; 
  })();
</script>
```

Comment: i tryed this one"echo '<script> (function() { document.getElementById("btn1").disabled = true; })(); </script>';", but it disables the button even if the condition is false...

Answer (score 1):

You need to output suitable client side code. You can't just use client side JS directly in your PHP.

```
echo '<script>document.getElementById("btn1").disabled = true;</script>';
```

But you would probably be better off just setting the attribute:

```
echo '<button etc etc disabled>etc etc</button>';
```